# How to loop animation

Tags: animation

How can i loop an animation of running character[image]?

Comment: you can use the NLA window and create a strip from your animation, check some NLA tutorials on youtube

Comment: If you mean in the viewport, just set the value of End in the Timeline to be after your last keyframe, in your case I guess it'll be 18 or 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure that the pose of your objects first keyframe is the same as the one of the last keyframe in the period you want to loop. This can be done by duplicating the first column of keyframes in the Dope Sheet and moving it to the end of the period.

Here are some ways to loop:

- at the Timeline: just set the end of your playback/rendering range to the last keyframe and play the result in a loop
- in the Dope Sheet: duplicate all keyframes <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and move them after your existing
- in the Graph Editor: use loop modifiers for everything animated

Here`s an example using the first method
[image: with breaks]

Answer (score 1):

For those who had to search for the *Loop Modifier* in *Graph Editor*, the name is: *Extrapolation Mode > Cyclic*, and can be found in the *Channel Menu*

[image]